# How to select rows from a data frame with replacement

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame defined as follows:

```
t1 <- data.frame(x=c("A","B","C"),y=c(5,7,9))

> t1
  x y
1 A 5
2 B 7
3 C 9
```

and a vector of picks:

```
picks <- c("B","C","B")
```

How do I get these rows, with replacement, in this order selected from the data frame?
I want:

```
x  y
B  7
C  9
B  7
```

I tried

```
> t1[t1$x %in% picks,]

  x y
2 B 7
3 C 9
```

and several other combinations of match, grep, which, etc and cannot get out what I want.  It seems like it should be easy but I'm not finding the path.

Comment: Have a look at `?match`.  It will work.  You need the numerical indices. `match(picks, t1$x, 0L)`

Comment: Thank you!  That worked - I was putting my inputs to match backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can perform an right join using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
picks <- data.table(x = picks)
setDT(t1)[picks, on = "x"]
#   x y
#1: B 7
#2: C 9
#3: B 7
```

By default the merged data.table is sorted according to `x` in `picks`.

Comment: You can also do: `setDT(t1)[.(x=picks), on="x"]`. The `x=` is not necessary as well from the next stable version.

Comment: Thanks - this is new to me so great to learn about this option.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use

```
setNames(t1$y, t1$x)[picks]
#B C B 
#7 9 7
```